# Methods for silhouette feature extraction

Tags: reference-request, pattern-recognition

Let's suppose I have an image of a person and its corresponding background. Using OpenCV I can relatively easily get a silhouette of the person from the image.

I am doing a project on human recognition using silhouettes and the only things I came up with for feature extraction are so called Granlund coefficients derived from Fourier coefficients and [Hu moments](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#humoments) which provide me with features I can send to various classifiers I have.

What I am further curious about is what other methods are there, if any, for feature extraction from silhouettes?

EDIT: In accordance with the first commentator, I will expand my question. As I said, I have tried with Granlund coefficients and Hu moments, both of them are well documented standard techniques which you can find in OpenCV documentation and IEEE Xplore digital library (Granlund coefficients).

Also, I didn't say anything specific about the features, I just want to know about various methods for silhouette feature extraction, other than the two mentioned above.

Comment: Which standard resources of your field have you checked? What kind of properties should methods have? e don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a [general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Please note also [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20) and [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion; you might want to improve your question as to avoid the problems explained there.

Comment: Since you're asking about established methods people have used, rather than the derivation of an algorithm, you might try cross-posting this to http://programmers.stackexchange.com . It attracts a more practical-minded crowd, and with the right tags you could grab the eye of an industry veteran who's done this before.